# How to limit ForeignKey users in custom groups in django

Tags: django, django-models

How to limit number of ForeignKey users in custom groups in django ? for example to 3?

```
class Group(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want to do. You want that a user can not appear more than 3 times in the table?

Comment: no,  just  limit number of users in group @Tartempion34

Answer (score 0):

```
if Group.objects.filter(user__isnull=False).count() > 3:
 print('this Group is full')
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that you'll have to override the save() method of your model:

```py
# in your model class
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # If you already reached the max, you raise an exception
    if Group.objects.count() == your_max_number:
        raise WhateverException
    # if no exception has been raised, you save your object
    super(Group, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to create a new one if it's completed you'll have to do that in your view.

```py
try:
    # try to add your user to the group
except WhatEverException:
    # create a new group and add user in it
```

Comment: ty! this is what I want, one more question if current group is max. which method to use to create new one?

Comment: in models when I count if Group.objects but need to count exactly User(FK) how can I?

Comment: you'll have to filter like Group.objects.filter(your_filter=your_value).count()